# PHP: deleting old images from array and displaying default image

Tags: php

I have a site that is used to display the last 7 days webcam images from a defined folder.

We have a code written for it that looks for the specific file types, deletes any that are over a defined age, and then puts them into an array along with their creation date. This array that is used to display the images in date order.

I want to amend the code so that if 7 days goes by without new images being uoloaded, a default "camera Offline" image is shown instead.

I have tried using array_push at the end to add my default image, but I cant get it to work. any suggestions?

---

```
// Array holding filename and creation date
$files = array();
// Delete all webcam files older than a week
function getFileList()
{

global $files;

    $captchaFolder  = './';         // Define the folder to clean 
    $fileTypes      = 'EZ*.jpg';    // Filetypes to check 
    $expire_time    = 10080;        // Define after how many minutes the files should get deleted


    // Find all files of the given file type
    foreach (glob($captchaFolder . $fileTypes) as $Filename)
    {
        $FileCreationTime = filectime($Filename);   // Read file creation time
        $FileAge = time() - $FileCreationTime;      // Calculate file age in seconds
        if ($FileAge > ($expire_time * 60))         // Is the file older than the given time span?
        {
            unlink($Filename);                      
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($files, array($Filename, $FileCreationTime));
        }
    }
    // Sort the array by $FileCreationTime
    $times = array();
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $times[] = $file[1];
    }
    array_multisort($times, SORT_ASC, SORT_NUMERIC, $files);
}

getFileList();
$numPics = count($files);

// Insert the options in the select element
function buildOptions()
{
    global $files;
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        $dt =  date ("D d/m/y H:i", $file[1]);
        echo "\t\t<option value=\"$file[0]\">$dt (UTC)</option>\n";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if the cam is offline for six days, only one photo is displayed, but after 7 days, i.e. the array is empty, you want a placeholder? Why not just `if(empty($files) $files = [['path/to/placeholder', 0]];` (or the current time instead of 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// check if the array is empty
if(empty($files)){

    // add a default image to the empty array (the timestamp doesn't matter because it will not be used)
    $files[] = array('default_image.png');

    // because it's empty you could also use:
    $files = array(array('default_image.png'));

}
```